# Не работает getJSON в javascript

Tags: javascript, json

[image]

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь взять с сайта данные в формате json, но у меня почему то не работает.
[image]
все данные которые он должен взять из viewers он должен записать в блок id=panel

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var channel = $('#name').html().toLowerCase();

var urls = 'https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/' + channel + '/chatters';


$.getJSON(urls, function(data) {

    var vie = JSON.parse(date);
    var viewers = vie.chatters.viewers;
    $('#panel').html(viewers);

});
```

});

Comment: `console.log(data);`  "Не работает"?? ошибки в консоли? что Вы планируете увидеть внутри панели?

Comment: Ошибка случайно не `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`?